# TestNG @Factory with Spring's @DirtiesContext

Tags: java, spring, testng

We use Spring's @DirtiesContext annotation quite liberally throughout our test code to guarantee no side effects between test classes. I recently learned about TestNG's @DataProvider and @Factory and some test in my code base would really benefit from this approach.
However, I found that @DirtiesContext causes the Spring beans to be shutdown too early, namely after the last test method of the first test instance the factory created.

A broken down version of my current setup looks like this

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SomeSpringContex.class })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    Database database;

    private final String configParameter;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "testSetup")
    public TestClass(String configParameter) {
        this.configParameter = configParameter;
    }

    @DataProvider(name="testSetup")
    public static Object[][] createParameters() {
        return new Object[][] {
            { "param1" },
            { "param2" }
        };
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void useConfigParameter() {
       // use configParameter to set up test
    }

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        database.query("SELECT * FROM foo");
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {
        database.query("SELECT * FROM bar");
    }
}
```

This essentially creates two instances of TestClass, one set up with "param1" and one set up with "param2". Thus every test is run twice, as intended, and the output (in eclipse) looks something like this

- firstTest (with "param1") => SUCCESS
- firstTest (with "param2") => SUCCESS
- secondTest (with "param1") => SUCCESS
- secondTest (with "param2") => FAIL, because the Database bean, along with it's database connection, was shutdown already

When I remove the @DirtiesContext annotation the test methods all work fine, but in my actual tests I run into inter test problems. Is there a way to make @DirtiesContext and @Factory play nicely together?

Comment: Your test class may extend `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`. Otherwise, it could be a spring issue and you should consider to upgrade your spring version or open an issue on the spring project.